# TFS .net application Code is not running on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error while running the same code which my colleague is able to run fine on his machine..

**Error:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this?

Comment: So your machines differ. Does that mean that the correct WebMatric.Data assembly is not installed on your machine? Check the bin folder or GAC.Or you have a bitness (x86/x64) mismatch.

Comment: dear Waleed i tried to add different packages which are recommended in stack-overflow but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Like the Error message says, you are missing an assembly file. First make sure you have the right file located in the right directory.

Then you may check if you have a reference set to that assembly.

In Visual Studio: Right-click on your Project > Add > Reference... > check "WebMatrix.Data".
If the assembly is not listed there, you are missing the file.

If the assembly is part of a submodule and you are syncing your project by the Visual Studio Team Explorer: TFS sometimes has problems with syncing submodules. Try a 3rd party application to avoid those problems.

Comment: Dear could you please guide me in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this assembly is not referred from a package source. Better to install any external package from nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMatrix.Data/.

Alternatively, if you do not want to do that, I suggest is to create a folder(say dependencies) with solution (not a solution folder) and refer your assemblies from this folder. Checkin this folder to TFS along with solution so that anyone who is loading solution from TFS will get the required dependencies.